# Find $f(x)$ such that $f(x^2)=f(x)+1$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

This is a question I made for fun:

> Find all continuous $f:(1,\infty)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x^2)=f(x)+1$$

I was able to find one solution, namely $$f(x)=\log_2(\log_2x)$$Which I found by first realizing that 1.) $f$ is an even function and 2.) It satisfies: $$f(2^{2^{x}})=x$$ (by fixing $f(2)=0$ and substituting numbers of the form $2^{2^n}$ into the functional equation) then assumed that $f$ is the inverse of $2^{2^{x}}$. I then got an answer. But the question is to find all functions that satisfy the functional equation, and I assumed that $f$ is invertible, which doesn't have to be the case.

I remember seeing the functional equation $f(f(x))=6x-f(x)$ being solved by turning it into $a_2=6x-a_1$ or something like that and then turning the subscripts into powers, so maybe this could also be applied to the functional equation in question?

Comment: You run into trouble when $x=1$.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps it makes more sense to restrict the domain of the function to $\mathbb{R}-\{-1,0,1\}$

Comment: $f(x)=\log_2(\log_2|x|)$ is undefined for $x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: @Angelo These are the only continuous solution.

Comment: @Yanko, all the continuous functions $\,f:(1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}\,$ that satisfy $\,f(x^2)=f(x)+1\,$ are the following ones:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}g(x)&\text{if }\;2\leqslant x<4\\[5pt]f\!\left(\sqrt[2^n]x\right)+n&\text{if }\;2^{2^n}\leqslant x<4^{2^n}\\[5pt]f\!\left(x^{2^n}\right)-n&\text{if }\;\sqrt[2^n]2\leqslant x<\sqrt[2^n]4\end{cases}$$ where $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ and $\,g:[2,4)\to\Bbb R\,$ is any continuous function such that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to4^-}g(x)=g(2)+1\,.\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Claim:** all continuous solutions $f:(1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ take the following form: $$f(x) = g(\log_2 \log_2 x) + \log_2\log_2 x$$ where $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is any continuous function of period $1$. Further, the above defines a bijection between the set of continuous functions $(1,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ satisfying the given functional equation, and the set of continuous functions with period $1$. (So you can think of the periodic continuous functions as "parametrizing" solutions to your functional equation.)

**Proof.** Let $\mathcal C^0(\mathbb T^1)$ denote the set of continuous real-valued functions with period one (i.e. "functions on the 1-torus") and let $F\subset \mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$ denote the set of continuous functions solving the given functional equation. We will show that the above defines a function $\Phi:\mathcal C^0(\mathbb T^1)\to F$, and moreover that this function is bijective.

First, let $g\in \mathcal C^0(\mathbb T^1)$ be an arbitrary continuous periodic real-valued function. We know that the logarithm base $2$ is defined and continuous on $(0,\infty)$, and that it maps $(1,\infty)$ onto $(0,\infty)$ bijectively, hence $\log_2\log_2 x$ defines a continuous function on $(1,\infty)$. This means that $\Phi(g)$ as defined earlier is a continuous real-valued function $(1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$. Further, we can easily show that it satisfies the required functional equation:
\begin{align}
f(x^2)
&= g(\log_2 \log_2 x^2) + \log_2 \log_2 x^2 \\
&= g(\log_2(2\log_2 x)) + \log_2(2\log_2 x) \\
&= g(\log_2\log_2 x + 1) + \log_2\log_2 x + 1 \\
&= g(\log_2\log_2 x) + \log_2\log_2 x + 1 \\
&= f(x) + 1 \\
\end{align}
This shows that $\Phi:\mathcal C^0(\mathbb T)\to F$ is well-defined.

To see that it is injective, suppose that $\Phi(g_1) = \Phi(g_2)$. Then, for any $x\in\mathbb R$, we have that $\Phi(g_1)(2^{2^x}) = \Phi(g_2)(2^{2^x})$, since $2^{2^x} > 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, and therefore $2^{2^x}$ is in fact an element of the domains of these two functions. But substituting the definition of $\Phi$ into this equation yields $$g_1(x) + x = g_2(x) + x$$ and therefore $g_1(x) = g_2(x)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we conclude $g_1 = g_2$. Thus $\Phi$ is injective.

Finally we show that $\Phi$ is surjective. Let $f$ be an arbitrary continuous solution to your functional equation, and define $$g(x) = f(2^{2^x}) - x$$ Clearly $g$ is well-defined because $2^{2^x} > 1$ for all real $x$, and it is continuous because $2^{2^x}$ is a continuous function of $x$, and $f$ is also continuous. Further, we can see that $g$ has period $1$, because
\begin{align}
g(x+1)
&= f(2^{2^{x+1}}) - x - 1 \\
&= f((2^{2^{x}})^2) - x - 1 \\
&= f(2^{2^{x}})+1 - x - 1 \\
&= f(2^{2^{x}}) - x \\
&= g(x)
\end{align}
so we may conclude that $\Phi(g) = f$, hence $\Phi$ surjective. This completes our proof.

Comment: After reading the proof (thanks for defining advanced notation unlike most other users), did you really need to prove that $\phi$ is bijective? And is $\phi=f$?

Answer (score 3):

*This solution is valid for the previous question where the domain was all of $\mathbb{R}$*

There are no solutions at all. Set $x=0$ you get

$$f(0) = f(0)+1$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Kamal Saleh I solved it when $f$ is continuous, I am not sure about the general case.

Comment: This is not correct. The domain of the function does not include 1, so g(1) in your solution does not exist.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer good point. let me see if I can fix that

Comment: See @jjagmath ‘s solution, which looks like it’s almost correct save for one detail

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer Oh I see, so there's no way to fix the current approach.

Comment: Nope, there are in fact a huge multitude of “unnatural” solutions. But if you impose another condition, for instance smoothness, maybe you can narrow it down to the class of functions you stated in your answer… I kind of doubt this too though, since there are some pathological smooth functions as well. Real-analytic might be necessary to fully narrow it down to that class

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer My solution is correct. If the detail you're talking about is the fact that the solutions are not continuous is because the OP changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

With the domain $(1,\infty)$ there are infinitely many solutions, all of which can be found as follows: take **any** function $g:[2,4) \to \Bbb R$ and define $f$ recursively as follows:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x)&\text{ if }2\le x < 4\\
f(\sqrt x) +1 &\text{ if } x\ge4\\
f(x^2)-1 &\text{ if } 1<x<2
\end{cases}
$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150041/discussion-on-answer-by-jjagmath-find-fx-such-that-fx2fx1); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.